# How do I pick an item up without getting physics from it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making my character be possible to pick an item up. When the player kills an enemy, the item jumps to the sky from the position where it dies, and it falls to the ground to be a pickable item. I'm currently using capusle collider detecting method to pick the item up (destroy obj, and item variable++ when they collides). It works well when I pick it up on the ground. But the problem is that when I try to collide with the item in the sky, the physics is applied to the character so the player feels like he's blocked jumping by the falling item. This also happens when the player collides with the item while he's walking right beneath it. How do I fix this problem? I want to detect the collision between the item and the player without applying physics to the player.

I cannot just remove collision relationship with everylayer because the item needs to detect the platform and player layer.

Comment: Seems you have a rigidbody in the item. Maybe you can mark it as "IsKinematic" to omit the physics there. ?

Comment: Maybe you should use triggers for pickup (switch to `OnTriggerEnter`).  For the items physical collider, assign it to a layer and disable/uncheck the collision matrix checkbox for `Player`-`Item`.  This way the item still collides with the world, but not with the player.

Comment: Then how does the player pick the item up? It should collide with the player anyway to be picked up.